# cant play the video with the cgi script

Tags: html, apache, perl, video, cgi

I really don't know the how to ask this.
I am trying to play the video file from `cgi-script`.

Here is my code(it is working):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

print $cgi->header(
        -type=> "text/html" );

print <<EOF;
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src='http://127.0.0.1/video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 
EOF
```

In the `<source>` I am giving path of the video.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

print $cgi->header(
        -type=> "text/html" );

print <<EOF;
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="home/praveen/ubuntu_Workspace/c/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 
EOF
```

In this code the `<source>` is the path to my local directory. 
Here where i am stuck when i give the path (like `/home/praveen/ubuntu_workspace/c/video.mp4`) to my local drive it cannot be able to locate the path.

Here is my `error.log` file is writing:

```
[Fri Jan 29 13:06:43 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/home, referer: http://127.0.0.1/test.cgi
```

After some googling I came to know that in web server it will not serve the html in the context of `file:///` tree.

Please somebody tell me what should I do to access local files also.(like `/home/praveen/../test.mp4`. Why it is giving error like that.

Please suggest me on this where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The "src" attribute on the `<source>` element requires a URL, not a filesystem path. If the source you give is:

home/praveen/ubuntu_Workspace/c/video.mp4

This is a relative URL and (assuming no web server rewrite rules) the server will assume that the "home" refers to a directory called "home" which is a subdirectory of the directory where your HTML file is. And that doesn't exist, so you get a "file does not exist" error.

If the source you give is:

/home/praveen/ubuntu_Workspace/c/video.mp4

This is an absolute URL and (again, assuming no web server rewrite rules) the server will look for the "home" directory in the root of the web space on the server. That's probably `/var/www/` or something like that. Again, the directory doesn't exist and you'll get the same error.

Your web server only has access to files within the web space.That's a security feature. You really don't want to go changing that.

The solution to this is to move your video files into a directory inside the web space for this host.

**Update:** One other option would be to configure your web server to support [per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) and to put the video files in there.